# mcrypt encryption equivalent of openssl_encrypt

Tags: php

I need openssl_encrypt equivalent of the below mcrypt encryption.

```
public function encrypt($str) {
        $key = 'zXmW8rXT7id3s06m';
        $blocksize = mcrypt_get_block_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
        $pad = $blocksize - (strlen($str) % $blocksize);
        $str = $str . str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
        $td = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, '', MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, '');

        $iv = @mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($td), MCRYPT_RAND);

        mcrypt_generic_init($td, $key, $iv);
        $cyper_text = mcrypt_generic($td, $str);
        $rt = base64_encode($cyper_text);
        mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
        mcrypt_module_close($td);

        return $rt;
    }
```

I tried like below. But both the outputs are not same.

```
public function openSslEncrypt($str){
        $cipher = "AES-128-CBC";
        $key = 'zXmW8rXT7id3s06m';
        if (in_array($cipher, openssl_get_cipher_methods()))
        {
            $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher);
            $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen);
            $ciphertext_raw = openssl_encrypt($str, $cipher, $key, $options=OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
            $ciphertext = base64_encode( $ciphertext_raw );
            return $ciphertext;
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is no equivalent for Mcrypt's Rjindael. You have to re-encrypt everything.

Comment: Also you're mixing ECB and CBC, [never use ECB if you have a choice] _and_ using different, random IVs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to find solution for this after some tries. Posting the code below.

```
public function openSslEncrypt($str){
        $cipher = "aes-128-ecb";
        $key = 'zXmW8rXT7id3s06m';
        if (strlen($str) % 16) {
            $pad = 16 - (strlen($str) % 16);
            $str = $str . str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
        }
        if (in_array($cipher, openssl_get_cipher_methods()))
        {
            $ciphertext_raw = openssl_encrypt($str, $cipher, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA);
            $ciphertext = base64_encode( $ciphertext_raw );
            return $ciphertext;
        }
    }
```

Comment: PHP does not have named parameters, so `$options=OPENSSL_RAW_DATA` literally sets that variable in the current scope and uses its value as the 4th positional parameter.